# Genenerate address offline, but blockchain knows about my address

Tags: address, public-key, address-generation

I generate new address in client. I hear that blockchain doesn't know about it. Blockchain will know about it when I use this address for transaction.

My example:
I generate this address(offline): 1J1JqUPqKq4XvrDRioMSMYKrwL3wKdJ1Fe
I haven't used yet. How does website blockchain.info know about my address??? https://blockchain.info/address/1J1JqUPqKq4XvrDRioMSMYKrwL3wKdJ1Fe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It only knows anything about the address because you asked about it.

Since the address has never appeared in the blockchain, all it knows is [what can be seen](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_Bitcoin_addresses) from the address: its hash160 value. This is the hexadecimal version of what is encoded in your address, which is a hash of your public key via the [algorithm explained here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_Bitcoin_addresses).

Comment: okey, but if I change last two letters in address: 1J1JqUPqKq4XvrDRioMSMYKrwL3wKdJ1Fe -> 1J1JqUPqKq4XvrDRioMSMYKrwL3wKdJ1eF . Blockchain.info doest't know about it, but it also address or not?

Comment: An address includes a 32-bit checksum. If you carelessly change some portion of the address, the new address will most likely be invalid. Blockchain.info recognizes this and rejects it.